# How to handle result from both parent (via super) and child method calls?

Tags: ruby

Consider this clunky contrived example:

```
class Notification
  def should_send?
    enrollment_status ? true : false
  end
end

class Sms < Notification
  attr_reader :enrollment_status

  def should_send?
    super(enrollment_status)
    # a method call dealing with logic specific to text messages would go here
  end
end

class PhoneCall < Notification
  attr_reader :enrollment_status

  def should_send?
    super(enrollment_status)
    # a method call dealing with logic specific to phone call would go here
  end
end
```

This example will not work but, imagine that there are quite a few more Notification sub-classes and it's not very dry to add `false if user.unenrolled?` to every sub-class. However, each sub-class will also implement its own custom logic. A crucial consideration is that the parent Notification check needs to supercede the custom logic in the sub-classes. Put another way, if the parent method call returns true, then defer to the results in the child method call and if the parent call returns false, the original child method call should return false regardless of the custom logic.

A few notes/questions:

- I understand this example has some quirks, it's odd but it fairly represents the limitations of existing work.
- Is it possible to short circuit out of the super method call and return that result prior to the execution of the logic in the child method?
- Should/can I pass the whole child to the parent in a super call and compose the entire logic check there?
- My thinking may be off here, have I got this all mixed up? Is there a better way to manage checking both child and parent results?

Answer (score 1):

To do what you're asking for:

```rb
class Notification
  attr_reader :enrollment_status

  def should_send?
    !!enrollment_status
  end
end

class Sms < Notification
  def should_send?
    super && call_sms_method
  end
end

class PhoneCall < Notification
  def should_send?
    super && call_phone_method
  end
end
```